# Pixel-perfect 'nearest neighbor' scaling

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, nearest-neighbor

I have an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) as shown below. When zooming in (enlarging the image), I want to **preserve the pixels as much as possible**. Hence, interpolation should be avoided. E.g. Zooming 1700% implies a solid 17x17 pixel area for each and every pixel. (I understand this becomes problematic for values like 1730%.)

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="C:\test.png"
       <!-- 4 important values -->
       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
       UseLayoutRounding="True"
       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
```

**Q:** What combination of these four settings is the best in this case?

Comment: Is this an instance where it might be resolved by just embedding it in a ViewBox?

Comment: Give it a shot, sounds like what you're looking for without the extra hassle. :)